# How to teach Gemma model my mother tongue (Kannada - one of the oldest Indic languages)

Tags: transformer, large-language-models, fine-tuning

I'm interested in teaching the Gemma 2B model my mother tongue ([Kannada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kannada) - one of the oldest Indic languages). The pre-trained model doesn't work well with the mentioned language, so I thought of teaching the model but I'm very new to this field of training and fine-tuning LLMs. But based on some research I've planned the below steps:

1. Prepare the Dataset - luckily I found [some dataset](https://huggingface.co/datasets/Cognitive-Lab/Kannada-Instruct-dataset) on HF.
2. Train the Tokenizer for the language and enrich the vocabulary of the Gemma model with the newly obtained tokens from the dataset using a newly trained Tokenizer.
3. Here is where I'm confused

   a. Should I simply fine-tune the model? - maybe using LoRA or QLoRA kind of techniques.

   b. I read about a concept called [Continually Pre Train](https://arxiv.org/abs/2302.03241), should I give this a try?

3 (b) looks promising to me but I'm not able to find much explanations and code examples on the internet about how to achieve this.

**Note:** I'm looking for a very basic model and performing this for learning purposes and I should be able to do this on my Google Colab Notebook.

I'm seeking some guidance here on how to proceed and some code examples for achieving this.